# Saving a bitmap and naming it as an inputted string

Tags: android, filenames

I've been having an issue with the file's name when I was saving an image.

```
String fileName = currentDate + currentTime + personName;

private void saveImage()
{
    View u = mView;
    ScrollView z = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scroll_view);
    int totalHeight = z.getChildAt(0).getHeight();
    int totalWidth = z.getChildAt(0).getWidth();

    Bitmap b = getBitmapFromView(u, totalHeight, totalWidth);


    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
        b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
        MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), b, "Screen", "screen");
    }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

When the file is output, the file's name is set to a series of numbers (e.g.: "1457223074488") instead of the string. 
 If there's anyone that may have a solution, please let me know.

Comment: What is currentDate and currentTime? Are those times in milliseconds maybe?

Comment: currentDate is date format mm/dd/yy and currentTime is time format HHMM

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the wrong version of `MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage`.  The one you're calling right now simply takes a Bitmap as input to save.  It doesn't know anything about the file you created.  It's not defined in the javadoc what the name of the file it will use for your bitmap.

Instead, you probably want to be calling it with the name file you created:

```
MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), fileName, "Screen", "screen");
```

Also, you should note in the javadoc that MediaStore will create a thumbnail for the image, and the name of the file it creates for that could be anything it wants.